# How to use Microsoft Dynamics CRM in soup UI

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am very new to Microsoft Dynamics CRM. I am trying to connect to my demo account through REST API using SOUP Ui. But every time I am getting authorization failed error( Error code 401). How should I pass my login credentials in HTTP Header. I am not using SDK, I am just making a rest API call. Please help me in this. If my question is too broad please let me know. I will update my question.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how Soup UI works but it sounds like you will need to provide login credentials.

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt595798.aspx) has a C# sharp example.

```
private HttpClient getNewHttpClient(string userName,string password,string domainName, string webAPIBaseAddress)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domainName) });
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webAPIBaseAddress);
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
    return client;
}
```

---

> Can u tell me exactly what should I use for the argument domainName

This depends on exactly what type of CRM setup (online, on-premise, IFD) you are trying to connect to.

Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695810(v=crm.7).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602970.aspx) which demonstrates various connection string details. The samples are using a different connection mechanism to use the SOAP services, but I would expect the username, domain, to be the same with the REST endpoint.

---

> Do u know which are all authentication types Microsoft Dynamics CRM
>   accepts like (Basic, NTLM, etc) ?

[Authenticate users in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328497.aspx)

> Microsoft Dynamics CRM supports three security models for
>   authentication: claims-based authentication, Active Directory
>   authentication, and OAuth 2.0. The type of authentication used depends
>   on the type of deployment your application is accessing, Microsoft
>   Dynamics CRM Online or Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016, and if your
>   application is using the Web API or the Organization Service.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can u tell me exactly what should I use for the argument domainName.?

Comment: Thanks @James Wood . I am using CRM-online. Do u know which are all authentication types Microsoft Dynamics CRM accepts like (Basic, NTLM, etc) ?

Comment: Thanks Your answer and suggestion helped a lot.